# Sorting an integer's digits in descending order

Tags: javascript, sorting, digits

So say we have a number -- **123456** for simplicity sake. I needed a function that would take that as input and return 654321, or say 53283940, same would return 98543320.

I have something seems to work I'm just not sure if it's done with best practice, it seems like it can be re-factored into something cleaner. Here is what I have, any help? I'm new trying to improve, thank you.

```
function descendingOrder(a){
    let b = Array.from(a.toString()).map(Number); // map int into array
    let stringResult = b.sort().reverse().join(""); // sort in ascending, then reverse & join
    let intResult = ~~stringResult; // double bitwise operator to turn str to int
    return intResult; // return final int
}
```

Comment: that is what it takes. You'll be offered some optimizations but they all do the same (but more efficiently).

Comment: you need no map with `Number`, because you can sort by string, as you do later.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Ah good point, thanks.

Comment: Mixing `Number` and `~~` to do the same operation in two different ways could be improved.

Comment: The biggest problem with javascript numbers is that they are limited in size. So if you try your function on some big one, like `1999999999999`, the result will be surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const sortNumber = (a) => Number([...("" + a)].sort().reverse().join(""));

const test1 = 123456;
console.log(sortNumber(test1));

const test2 = 53283940;
console.log(sortNumber(test2));
```

or

```js
const sortNumber = (a) => ~~Array.from(a.toString()).sort().reverse().join("");

const test1 = 123456;
console.log(sortNumber(test1));

const test2 = 53283940;
console.log(sortNumber(test2));
```

Comment: This returns a string, I need it to return a number. Nice solution otherwise!

Comment: You can prefix the return value with a '+' to cast to an int: `(a) => +Array.from(a.toString()).sort().reverse().join("")`

Comment: Can I prefix it with double bitwise as well? `~~`

Comment: Yes, be wary of truncating floats for general use though

Comment: @exception-io, return will be number,  cast to Number like this Number( [...("" + a)].sort().reverse().join(""))