# What's the best way to sort the digits in an integer?

Tags: javascript

Is there a more performant way then putting the numbers in an array and calling .sort() ?

Comment: You should try and measure your own solutions

Comment: The "most performant way" and using JavaScript are kind of contradictory. I suspect the most performant would be to use C or Rust and instead of converting the `number` to a `string` and `split`ting it, getting the digits using modulo `10^n`..

Comment: @trincot Those are for reversing, not sorting.

Comment: True, let me find them for sorting... there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56710566/5459839).

Comment: what result is expected for `10000` ?

Comment: You cant have prefix zeros in a number

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably get better performance when avoiding the conversion to and from string. And to sort, you could use counting sort: there are only 10 different digits, and after counting their occurrences you can reconstruct the output number:

```
function countingSortDigits(n) {
    const count = Array(10).fill(0);
    for (; n; n = (n - n % 10) / 10) {
        count[n % 10]++;
    }
    for (let digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++) {
        for (let j = count[digit]; j; j--) {
            n = n*10 + digit;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Here is a comparison of execution times:

```js
function toStringSort(n) { // Asker's implementation 
    return parseInt(n.toString().split("").sort().join(""));
}

function countingSort(n) {
    const count = Array(10).fill(0);
    for (; n; n = (n - n % 10) / 10) {
        count[n % 10]++;
    }
    for (let digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++) {
        for (let i = count[digit]; i; i--) {
            n = n*10 + digit;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

function timeIt(f, repeat) {
    const start = performance.now();
    while (repeat--) f();
    return performance.now() - start;
}

const timing = { toStringSort: 0, countingSort: 0 };
// Execute the functions for 1000 different random integers
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e15);
    timing.toStringSort += timeIt(toStringSort.bind(null, n), 1000);
    timing.countingSort += timeIt(countingSort.bind(null, n), 1000);
}
console.log(timing);
```